# Bounds on tape alphabet size of a Turing Machine encoding

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

What is the max possible ratio between the tape alphabet size and the total encoding size in an asymptotic sense? Say if I take some TM and add more and more symbols to its tape alphabet, will the encoding size grow linearly? or might it grow exponentially? Or being more specific:

Let $L \subseteq \{ \langle M \rangle : M$ is a TM$\}$, and let $D$ a TM deciding L with worst case time complexity of $\Theta(f(n,k))$, where $k= |\Gamma|$ and $\Gamma$ is the tape alphabet of the input TM.

Does this imply D runs in $\Theta(f(n,n))$ where $n$ is the input size? (i.e, $n=|\langle M \rangle|$)

Comment: The answer depends on the encoding. What encoding do you have in mind?

Comment: I was thinking of the general case "is there an encoding such that the claim is false?" i.e, such that $D$ runs in some $o(n)$ worst case time

Comment: The machine $D$ might have to spend time $n$ just to verify that the input is well-formed. Consider for example an encoding $M \mapsto \langle M \rangle a^{2^{|\langle M \rangle|}}$. If it weren't for the necessity to verify the encoding, the machine would run in logarithmic time.

Comment: I think a better question is to replace $\Gamma$ with $f(n,k)$ where $k=|\Gamma|$ and $n$ with $f(n,n)$, as I see now it misses some interesting part